# Prevent to delete insecure code from embed code

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

I want to create a couple of links which will open new document based on template like:

```
   <a href="ms-word:nft|u|http://.../DocLib4/Forms/template.dotx|s|http://.../DocLib4">Create Document</a>
```

This link is perfectly works when I add it in html page. But when I want to add this link to a wiki-page by using embed code, after saving a page, server removes a link, because it's insecure code.

How to prevent this server behavior?

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

It is the default behaviour of SharePoint, try the below workaround

- Save the code in a text file, save it somewhere on your SharePoint
  site collection.
- Next, place a Content Editor Web Part (CEWP) on the page and edit the
  webpart settings. At the top, add the link to the file and click
  “Apply” to save the changes.